# Searched products description error

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm working on [this](http://toolskaart.com). If we go to a particular product, then the product will be displayed perfectly. But if we find any product by writing in search column, it will show like [this](http://toolskaart.com/index.php/dia-19mm-carbide-drill-1901.html). The page that render this display is the same. as I guess the problem is in "$parentId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentId();" where the problem is "current category". Please suggest some if condition, so that it will display content currectly for both navigated and searched item. My code for this goes like this. Please help me on this.

```
<?php 
$parentId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentId();
$parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
$parentname = $parent->getName();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go to product page from category page, Magento saves that path, it's also shown in url and breadcrumbs. When you go on product page directly, Magento doesn't know anything about current category, because product could have many categories or don't have category at all.

You could try to get current category from registry and then check if it's null:

```
$currentCat = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($currentCat) {
$parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($currentCat->getParentId());
//do what you need with parent
}
```

You also could obtain *some* parent category by getting all categories of current product, and getting parent category of one of them, if this is required for you product page layout.